# Material UI dimensions

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am just getting started with Material UI components for React. While I am still getting used to not styling my own components, but rather importing out-of-the-box methods I find it hard to assimilate them to my project.

Often I find that the components are way too large for my layout, caused by too much padding/margin.

Specifically, I'm implementing [Selects](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/). I scouted the docs and SO for ways to adapt the size (height) to my project, but due to the components having a half dozen sub-components the dimensions never add up.

What is an effective way to adjust a component's dimensions, and align all dependent's heights / widths ?

So far I have tried wrapping the component in a MUITheme, and added CSSBaseline, both taken from the docs, but to no avail. I also attempted to work with the [classes](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) which didn't have any effect.

I went directly into CSS but was only able to set the padding of the top-level wrapper: #outlined-age-native-simple. This is the only selector i can reach which actually changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `theme.spacing.unit` via

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({ spacing: { unit: 4 }}) // default is 8
```

[How to use a theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/)

Be aware that many components have hard coded paddings/margins according to the [material design guidelines](https://material.io/design/).

Comment: This did not work. I think it must be that the component has the mentioned hard-coded spacing. How is it then that people use these components even when they have different needs for spacing ?